# Dataflow Python Operator fails

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dataflow

We load data from csv file to BigQuery table using DataflowPythonOperator. It was working fine until two days ago. Now, it refuses to start. It starts the worker and does not proceed from there.

We also  have JavaOperator and that works fine. We are seeing this issue in PythonOperator only.

Can someone help us debug this issue?

Comment: Can you fix the version in your requirements.txt file? Something like : apache-beam==2.13.0. and open an issue on the GitHub: https://github.com/apache/beam

Comment: I tried adding apache-beam==2.13.0 to requirements file, and that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Is this pipeline work locally? Is it only on dataflow platform that it failed?

Comment: I have not tried locally. Need to setup local environment. This was working fine until Friday morning.

Comment: Try on cloud shell, many of useful component are already installed. It's just for diagnose if it's beam or environment issue

Comment: Per your suggestion, added apache-beam==2.13.0 to requirements file, and created worker job in different region and we get the same error. Here is the part of the log specific to this error. 

...

jsonPayload:
  line: exec.go:64
  message: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'

...

serialized_pb=_b('\n\x15google/rpc/code.proto\x12\ngoogle.rpc ...

...

  message: '  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/rpc/code_pb2.py",
    line 23, in <module>'

Comment: If it's protobuf issue, it's maybe an update on the Dataflow environment that broke this. Did you finally had time for trying locally ?